# Конфликт портов

Tags: com-порт, java

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть com-порт, который передает иногда данные, и есть программа, которая получает данные с ком-порта и пишет в лог.

Надо в параллельку подключится к ком-порту и получать данные.

Я пробую через JSSC.

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");    
serialPort.openPort();    
serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);    
boolean flag = true;    
while(flag){
 System.out.println(serialPort.readString());
}
serialPort.closePort();
```

Естественно, пробовать на рабочей машине рискованно. На своей пишу в порт

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();
            serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
            serialPort.writeString("This is a test string");
            serialPort.closePort();
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

Запускаю, естественно, вначале программу на чтение, а потом - на запись. Вот тут-то и происходит конфликт портов. Вторая программа пишет, что порт занят (занят-то он первой программой). Таким образом, я и на рабочей машине заблокирую порт и "секир мне голова".

Может, кто подскажет, как правильно реализовать параллельное получение данных  с ком-порта?

Comment: нельзя одновременно и писать двумя программами в один порт. Будет бяка.  Подобные задачи решаются другими способами - создается отдельно программа, которая пишет/читает, а другие программы работают через нее.

Максимум, что можно сделать, так это одна программа читает пишет, а другие "снифают" обмен.

Comment: @KoVadim а можно сделать зеркало порта? Т.е. порт 2 будет следить за портом 1 и получать то же самое, что и первый порт?

Comment: если только читать - то можно. Есть такая программа - [portmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx). Там же описан принцип работы. Вот только получиться ли это на java закодировать... не знаю.

Comment: @KoVadim интересная программа. Можно потом парсить её лог - вот только это костыль... Нельзя ли тот же самый функционал реализовать средствами явы?

Comment: Эти обе программы пишете вы, или та, что пишет, уже есть и её трогать нельзя? Работать с одним портом двумя программами не разумно, тем более для просто записи в лог.